# Inline list-style-type on ul is not overriding external style applied on all the ul tag

Tags: html, css

I know there are many times same question has been asked, but none of them is answering my question

I have following style defined in my external css

```
ul {list-style: none !important}
```

now in my html I have defined following

```
<ul style = "list-style-type:circle><li>hello</li></ul>
```

but this is not working but why?

[Live Website Link](http://bubovi.com/pricing)

Comment: `list-style-type` css property is meant for `li` elements whereas `list-style` css property is meant for `ul` elements.

Answer (score 2):

You have `ul {list-style: none !important}` defined at least three times in your CSS. Clean up your code.

Also, this is a terrible use of !important. A global hammer like that will end up needing to be overridden far too many times.

Comment: I have removed and now it is only in one file, but still not working

Comment: Take out the `!important` COMPLETELY from EVERYWHERE. Having that in your CSS even once will override the inline style declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding body selector `body ul{list-style: none !importan;}`

Comment: If you see the code in your inspector, the `ul{list-style: none !importan;}` is active in his ul. So it will change nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You've really messed up with CSS. using !important is the last resort.
I'd advice to fix those things, but if it's not possible, read this article:
http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't work when doing inline or external CSS then why not either create a new class for ul,li,a or use javascript to change the list styling onload=""

```
ul {list-style-type:none;}
<ul><li>hello</li></ul>

ul.circle {list-style-type:circle;}
<ul class="circle"><li>hello</li></ul>
```